# .NET HttpWebRequest Timeout property not working

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a Console application which calls multiple Web Api but somehow it is getting timeout error.

I increased timeout to 10 minutues but its still timing out on 2 minutes.

Below is a sample code.

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.2.2/web/movielist"); 
req.Timeout = 600000;
```

Comment: Why are you using `WebRequest` anyway? It's majorly out-of-date. `HttpClient` would be a better idea.

Comment: this code does not have problem .and it will change the timeout. mabye somewhere else you have problem

Comment: Last option is HttpClient only but i would like to know why timeout is not working. Code is already developed with HttpWebRequest dont want to change it again.

Comment: From performance perspective HttpWebRequest is better. I am calling API several times(2000)

Comment: Please show more code and the exact exception when timeout.

Comment: Cuious to know why you think _"From performance perspective HttpWebRequest is better"_.

Comment: I read this in one of the blog. I will check that in realtime.

Answer (score -1):

`WebRequest.Create()` is obsolete

use `HttpClient` instead of that and it has timeout property

See this article for more information [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)

With your code the timeout will change
[image: Click here]

Comment: Last option is HttpClient only but i would like to know why timeout is not working. Code is already developed with HttpWebRequest dont want to change it again.